# Чтение времени из бинарного файла

Tags: c#, delphi, время

В двоичном файле содержится 8 байт типа TDateTime (Дата и Время), 
как в C# считать и преобразовать в тип DateTime ?

Comment: А какой именно формат хранения данных там?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не знаю.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в бинарном файле содержатся дельфовые TDateTime? И их нужно корректно считать в приложении C#?

Comment: @kami скорее всего да..

Comment: хм... если вы не знаете исходный формат файла - вы не сможете правильно его прочитать. Вне зависимости от того, на каком языке вы пишете.

Comment: @kami из условий я знаю, что он 8 байт и Тип: TDateTime и комментарий (Дата и время обновления данных)

Comment: TDateTime в Delphi это простой Double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку в Delphi для хранения даты\времени используется тип Double, то можно прочитать значение времени в переменную типа double.
А далее попробовать сконвертировать в `System.DataTime` в C#.
Например, попробуйте так:

```
  Double dbl = 65985.3333; //Значение прочитанной переменной из бинарника.
  DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dbl)
```

Comment: double time получился равен 1.92571966779543E-319
dt получился {30.12.1899 0:00:00}

Comment: Вероятно, происходит что-то не то... Пруф: http://blogs.nimblebrain.net/index.php/converting-tdatetimes-to-system-datetimes-and-back?blog=2

Comment: Твой способ работает, просто определенным образом надо было считать, поменять байты и биты в определенном порядке ,а после уже массив байтов пере собрать , преобразовать и дабл, а потом уже во время! Спасибо тебе !

Comment: Не за что. Да и способ это не мой ) Просто изначально предполагалось, что эти 8 байт из бинарника будут читаться именно как TDataTime Delphi, т.е. как раз Double, а потом уж переводим их в DataTime в C#. В любом случае, рад. что заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю когда у меня была подобная задача, решалась довольно просто в структуре создавалась переменная `public DateTime t_k;` и в неё читались данные с бинарного файла с помощью `Marshal`